# OpenCV 3 RC 1 causes LNK2001

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"

#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_core300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_highgui300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_imgproc300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_imgcodecs300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_core300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_calib3d300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_imgproc300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_features2d300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_flann300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_hal300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_highgui300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_ml300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_objdetect300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_photo300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_shape300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_stitching300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_superres300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_ts300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_video300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_videoio300.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_videostab300.lib")

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    cv::Mat img;// cv::Point p; this compiles fine but with cv::Mat not.
}
```

this creates LNK2001 for the Symbol cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int*,int).
[ error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ""int _cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int*,int)"
(?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YAHPEAHH@Z)" ]

1.) I've builded opencv with vs2013 64 bit (Releas/Debug)

2.) I've added all opencv .lib

3.) I've added all opencv .dll

I get the error for Release and Debug

**Edit:**

1.) added pragma to show that all libraries are found.

2.) added full error output

3. ) added that cv::Point p; compiles

**Solved:** : See my last comment. I mark it as solved tomorrow.

Comment: Please state the full error message as part of the question not only in the headline. The LNK2001 is a missing symbol error. It is impossible to say what is missing without the full qualified error message.

Comment: Are you using the correct libraries? vs2013 is vc12.

Comment: yes, i'm builded opencv by myself with vs2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. I "succeded" in using headers from an older version (ugh). Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that errors because the linker doesn't know in which library to look for the method. You should check again the **x64** dependencies in *Project properties->Linker->Input->Additional dependencies*.

On the other hand you can add the additional dependencies before the main function via pragma comments, as follows:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_core300d.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_highgui300d.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "opencv_imgproc300d.lib")
...
```

If you are building a release version, remove the "d" letter before the extension.

Comment: I've already added the libraries (see 2). To make it more clear. I've added the pragmas.